# What is an Ethereum address

Tags: blockchain

How do I find my particular ethereum address and is it safe to give out? I need a very simplified version of how all this works. The research I’ve encountered so far is not helpful because I’m not a technical type.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of blockchains.

An ethereum address starts with 0x followed by a series of letters and numbers. Here is a random address: 0xadb83abbf7a8987afb76db33ed2855a07f5497c7

The ethereum address is safe to share. In fact, you must share it if you want people to send tokens to your address.

There are many ways for you to create an address. The most common way is to use a wallet such as Metamask (there are MANY wallets out there, some are on smartphones, some on desktop, some as browser extensions - just make sure to use a wallet that's popular and has a good reputation).

When you create an address, you also create a private key in the background (the wallet you use may not show this to you up front). The private key is private and should NEVER be shared with anyone. Most wallet allow you to restore your private key by using 12 or 24 random words. Make sure to note these words somewhere safe and NEVER share them with anyone. If you lose your wallet, you will be able to restore your access to your addresses by using these secret words.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a very high-level, non-technical explanation but I will give you the keywords in case one cares to dive in for more details.

There is some math involved but one doesn't need to be a mathematician or cryptographer to understand the gist of what's happening.

It's important to understand that the system is designed to prevent bad things from happening. Before Alice pays Bob, it's important to confirm that it is, indeed, Alice who is giving the instruction - otherwise, there would be chaos.

Ethereum uses "signatures" to know who is talking.

The signatures used are different from the squiggly lines on paper that are supposedly always the same and supposedly couldn't be produced by anyone else. They use a different principle that has been around for about 20 years - it works. https:// and other common security protocols rely on the same or similar process.

**"Public/Private Key Pairs"**

There are two "keys". One is public and safe to share and the other is a closely guarded secret used to sign. For any message, there is a signature that shows:

1. This is the message I signed (nothing has been altered).
2. Whoever signed it must know what the private is.
3. The *reciever* can calculate the public key from the message and the signature and figure out that it came from the public key.
4. Nothing about the secret key is revealed in the process. It's still a secret.

In case that is not clear:

**Sender (Alice):**

```
message + private key => signature
```

**Receiver**

```
message + signature => public key (Alice)
```

Bob can work out that Alice signed the message because only Alice could *do that* because only Alice knows the private (secret) key for her account.

**Ethereum Addresses**

Ethereum addresses have a public key and private key. Then, for various reasons, the to keys go into a function that makes a shorted, 20-bytes Ethereum address which is safe to pass around. E.g. send money to my address, "0x123..."

The receiver will only be able to *spend* the money if they can sign a transaction with the private key (top secret!) for that account.

Hope it helps.